# Conditional sentence in simple past

Tags: sentence-construction

Me and my friend decided to meet at school but at the last moment he changed his plan. But I went there on time, and surprisingly met another friend. After he left, my former friend arrived. How would I tell him?

a) If you had come on time you would have met xyz.

Or

b) If you were came one time you would have met xyz.

I want to use simple past

Comment: were came? or came?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is

> If you came on time you would have met xyz.

You may find the site [the-conjugation.com](https://www.the-conjugation.com//english/verb/come.php) useful.

There are real problems in your question. It should be something like this:

> My friend and I decided to meet at school but at the last moment he
>   changed his plans. I went there on time and surprisingly met
>   another friend. After he left, my former friend arrived ...

Comment: Although past tense and past perfect are often optional, I would definitely have opted in this case for **If you had come on time, you would have met.....** It excludes the ambiguity that arises with **If you came on time.....** (But I haven't marked your answer down.)

Comment: @Ronald Sole. Thanks. I would prefer the past perfect tense too.

Comment: If that's your preference, I suggest you amend your answer accordingly. Just use the **edit** option underneath it..